# Expand bash environment variable containing '('

Tags: windows, bash, environment-variables, msys2

Using bash from msys2 on windows 10, I can't seem to set a variable to a windows environment variable containing parens, ie '(', in a bash script.  For example,

```
p86="$PROGRAMFILES(x86)"
```

doesn't work, it expands the env variable `$PROGRAMFILES`.  I've tried escaping with backslashes, ie. "$PROGRAMFILES\(x86\)" but that doesn't work.  Is there a way around this in bash?  or are parens just not allowed in expanded variables?.  All of the windows variables are available in the process environment.

Comment: Whats the value of `echo $p86` after declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would use `${..}` to dereference a variable, eg:

```
echo "${a}bc"
```

will print the variable `$a` and then literal `bc`.

Try:

```
p86="${PROGRAMFILES(x86)}"
```

Alternative you should check the output of `env` to see if the variable is present:

```
env | grep PROGRAM
```

Comment: @jenesaisquoi One hack, not recommenced could be to grep the value from `env`: `env | grep -P '(?<=ProgramFiles\(x86\)=).*$'`, or `env | awk -F= '$1=="ProgramFiles(x86)"{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

Use the Windows command processor:

```
PFX86="$(cmd //c 'echo %ProgramFILES(x86)%')"
```